# How do I extract a HTML value using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to print out a value using Java and Selenium, the value is an HTML classname. I have tried to use the className identifier but either was doing it wrong or it didn't work.

This is the line of code:

```
System.out.println("Amount: " + driver.findElement(By.className("AB_num']")).getText());
```

I have the latest FF installed as well as Selenium.

Comment: Maybe show the snippet of the HTML?

Comment: @Train2019 You need to share Block of HTML code.

Comment: Why would you print the class name if you have to use class name to find the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have extra characters in the `classname` string: `"AB_num']"`. You should probably remove the `']` at the end of the string, like this:

```
System.out.println("Amount: " + driver.findElement(By.className("AB_num")).getText());
```

Comment: Wow...yep that was it. Thanks - sometimes a extra set of eyes is needed.